# How to specify optional arguments when using command prompt to call a python scipt

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I have successfully called the script using the command `python ccplay in_file.wav out_file.wav` in command prompt.

Now, I want to specify the optional CHANNEL argument which is 'audio0' or 'audio1'. I unsuccessfully tried `python ccplay 'audio0' in_file.wav out_file.wav` and a couple other variants.

Can someone give few examples how to call ccplay with several combinations of optional arguments. So that I can understand the general syntax.

Thank you.

The documentation of the scipt ccplay.py is given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to name the optional argument you use:

```
python ccplay in_file.wav out_file.wav --channel audio0
```